# PhantomJs: Can't find variable map

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner

I receive the following error:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9018/

INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
      ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
      at /Users/runtimeZero/code/vendor/inert/inert.min.js:589
```

I understand that I am including a file called [inert.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WICG/inert/master/dist/inert.js) 
which is using ES6 Map() . This is freaking out PhantomJs.

So I included core-js/es6/map.js polyfill in my karma config under files. 
However that does not resolve the issue.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 17):

I think PhatomJS is not supporting ES6 Map, so you need to try with a polyfill, 
I'm using babel polyfill `npm install babel-polyfill --save-dev`

```
files: [
    { pattern: 'node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js', instrument: false}, 
],
```

Comment: This should be the first entry in the array

Answer (score 8):

you need to install **es6-shim** and add it to your files section in karma config file.

```
npm install es6-shim --save
```

in your karma.config.js add it to your list of files

```
files: [
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js'
]
```

Comment: This brought another error for me: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap`